# How to nullify a django datetime field that has an existing value?

Tags: python, django, datetime

I have a model that has an optional datetime field.

```
class Order(models.Model):
    ...
    fulfilled = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

I can update the record's datetime to an actual datetime...

```
order = Order.objects.get(pk=99)
order.fulfilled = datetime.datetime.now()
order.save()

or... 

order.update(fulfilled=datetime.datetime.now())
```

Occasionally I need to remove the field's value or set it to an empty value. I can not figure out how to do this...

```
order = Order.objects.get(pk=99)
order.fulfilled = null #? or '' or... 0 or... 
order.save()
```

Comment: Why did I get a down vote?? Is something not clear here? I've dug all around the web trying to figure out how to empty/null out an existing record's datetime field's value. No comment? Just a downvote?

Comment: Has the model field always been nullable or has this changed since you first defined it? The reason I ask is because you will need to make sure the database schema allows nulls on that field. If this is the case, try setting the field to `None` (Python equivalent of `null`).

Comment: @Karl Yes, that was right, I just figured that out before seeing your comment. I had to set it to `None`. And yes, it has always been blank=True, and null=True. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just figured this out.

I need to set fulfilled to None.

```
order = Order.objects.get(pk=99)
order.fulfilled = None
order.save()
```

Comment: @karthikr I do like this suggestion but it should be noted that `post_save` and `pre_save` signals are not called when using `.update()` which effects me in this case. So `.save()` is the way to go for me for now :)